# Trouble with Facebook Graph API email field

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

Earlier this morning my code for getting a user's email address from Facebook was working fine, but now it returns everything **EXCEPT** for the user's email.

I get the fields using the Facebook C# SDK. I have the proper permissions to retrieve the email.

Similar problems from other developers:

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/391841610855516
- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/365297990174802

I tried using Facebook Developer's Graph API Explorer to test the json return fields and it is also missing the email field.

Comment: Are you sure your user hasn't revoked the email permission

Comment: I'm testing it with my own account and another new account I made today. And no, I did not revoke anything.

Comment: Ummm. Intresting.. haven't encountered this behavior myself, | Not an answer but a suggestion that instead of creating new user to test your app just go to Facebook Dev App Settings and go to roles for you app to create automatic test users Quickly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this after skimming through SO Q&A's and here is the solution for anyone who has encountered the same problem.

Apparently we were using a deprecated permission url string:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("permission", "email,more_permissions,blah,blah");
```

And should have been using this:

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("scope", "email,more_permissions,blah,blah");
```

Comment: can you provide the block of code that uses the parameters? I am having the same issue with the C# SDK and the code sample provided. Not getting the user's email.